# How professionals design they top notch websites?

Tags: website-design, interface-design, sketch-app, design-principles, website-templates

I'm a beginner web developer and I always create my websites using css framework such as Semantic-UI or bulma.io. Yesterday I saw this http://seanhalpin.io/ portfolio and I am amazed of how great, clean and unique the whole page looks. I also looked at the work section and I feel the same about just every webpage included in this portfolio.

I'm wondering, **how can I create such a clean and unique websites like this guy?** Maybe you know what the process of creating such websites looks like. Does he create any sketches on paper, or in illustrator, or what? I tried to use Sketch app but it's bit complicated and I don't think he uses that. **What is the key tool in creating beautiful, clean websites?**

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is what you're currently doing: looking at good web design. Figure out what you like about the layouts and try to replicate it. If you don't know how they achieved it, in Google Chrome you can right click and Inspect Elements to hover over parts you like and view the code.

From the look of that por folio, he employs many popular UI design decisions. Creating 100% width section DIVs with background images, one page website design and overlapping some elements in between sections such as images between two sections.

The key tool is to try to replicate what you like by studying design you like. Figure out what makes it good and then make it your own.